# issue while editing the object permissions on profile

Tags: profile, permission-sets

I am coming across the following issue on profile when editing the object permissions. The context in the error message is a permission set(Delete Service Request) which is giving modify all permission to the top level user. I unchecked all the permissions and tried to edit the profile object permissions, but no use any suggestions.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The Manage Cases permission requires delete access on cases.  If manage cases is selected for the profile, the profile must have delete. You can remove manage cases and should be able to save. If Manage Cases is part of your perms set, double check the perm set also has "delete" on cases.

You can vote for the [idea to have manage cases](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaViewhttps://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000iuOVAAY) without delete on the IdeaExchange.